# thymeleaf test case spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ShopControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;


    @Test
    public void showRegistrationForm() throws Exception {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        when(userService.showRegistrationForm(uuid)).thenReturn(new UserRegistration());
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/user/registration/"+uuid))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view()
                .name("registrationForm"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("data"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("reqDto"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists(uuid));
    }

}
```

I wrote this unit test to test the thymeleaf template. I am not able to run this because the UUID generated does not exist in the database.

This is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration/{uuid}")
public String showRegistrationForm(@PathVariable String uuid, Model model) {
    try {
        UserRegistration UserRegistration = this.userService.showRegistrationForm(uuid);
        model.addAttribute("user", true);
        model.addAttribute("uuid", uuid);
        model.addAttribute("reqDto", new RequestDto());
    } catch (UrlExpiredException e) {
        System.out.println("UrlExpiredException");
        model.addAttribute("exception", e.getMessage());
    } catch (UrlNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("UrlNotFoundException");
        model.addAttribute("exception", e.getMessage());
    }
    return "registrationForm";
}
```

this is in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you should mock your UserService?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: `@MockBean private UserService userService;` and then you can use Mockito e.g. `when(userService.showRegistrationForm).thenReturn(new UserRegistration());`

Comment: got this error:
`Caught exception while invoking 'beforeTestMethod' callback on TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@5f8edcc5]`
and this:
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;`

Comment: Show your code then...

Comment: It's the same. I just added this line that you wrote. I'll edit in the question

Comment: Your mockito version is too old, `MockCreationSettings<?> getMockCreationSettings();` exists since version 2.1.0

Comment: Updated to 2.17.0. And get the same error. UUID does not exist.